# Как исключить файл из сборки maven?

Tags: java, maven

Проект состоит из

```
myProject/src/myClasses/<all_java_classes.java>  //Все классы проекта
myProject/data/myDb.db                           //База данных
myProject/config.properties                      //Файл проперти
```

Сам pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ngrmr</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>OART</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <directory>out/maven_build</directory>
        <outputDirectory>myProject/out/classes</outputDirectory>
    </build>
</project>
```

Финальная сборка, как видите происходит в out/maven_build

Каким образом можно дополнить файл pom.xml, что бы файл базы данных и файл *.properties сохранялись неизменными в папке out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [maven resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/out</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>config.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/data</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>myDb.db</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Я только начал разбираться в вопросах связанных со сборкой с помощью maven - я правильно понимаю что данный способ подключает "плагин" мавена, который позволяет более расширенно параметризировать сборку?

Comment: Да. именно так. В maven большая часть необходимого функционала реализуется через плагины, которые описываются в секции `build > plugins`.

Comment: Я попробовал то что Вы посоветовали, но никаких изменений не произошло. Возможно я неверно понял ${project.basedir} - на что нужно заменить данную строку?

Comment: Кажется я понял что так и нужно написать: "${project.basedir}/..." . Закрываю вопрос, благодарю